# What is the purpose of the process RelayUploader in macOS?

Tags: macos

There is a running process called "RelayUploader" on a Mac machine. The user associated with that process is "nobody". What is the purpose of this process? Is it something legit or should this process be a security concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a proper answer, just some things you may want to try:

1. RelayUploader (aka Relay.Uploader) seems to be associated with a company called [TechSmith](https://www.techsmith.com/)... do you have any of their apps?
2. If you have a malware of virus scanner, you should run a scan on it.
3. Have you looked at the `info` available in `Activity Monitor`? (If not, open `Activity Monitor`, select the process from the list, then click the `i` icon in the Activity Monitor dialog). What does it say in the `Open Files and Ports` tab? Do you recognize any of these files?

Comment: thank you for your response. It is helpful! The computer does indeed have an app by TechSmith and when looking at the process info in the ActivityMonitor, the path of the RelayUploader process points to the TechSmith directory. I believe I am all set, but just for the sake of completeness, I will address your points 2 and 3. I should have mentioned it in the original post, a virus scan does not find any issues with this process. There is no "Open Files and Ports" tab in ActivityMonitor, which, I believe, means that the process is currently not using any files or ports. Thanks again!